# Mixed cookie configuration in a multi-tenant SaaS ASP.NET Core MVC solution

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-7.0

We're developing a multi-tenant SaaS solution based on ASP.NET Core 7 MVC deployed to an Azure App Service. We have a requirement from one customer who needs to embed the application into their ERP product via an iFrame.

We can set up the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` and Content Security Policy headers for them, however the site uses ASP.NET Identity with application cookies set to `Strict`.

This is configured in `Startup.cs` like this:

```cs
var authentication = services.AddAuthentication()
     .AddCookie(options =>
     {
         options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
         ...
     });
```

Unfortunately, because this is set at application level, there doesn't appear to be a way to set cookie settings per tenant.

Is there a way to override the default "Strict" mode for a specific customer dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this repo](https://github.com/enzonunziata/CustomAuthentication/blob/master/CustomAuthentication.Part2/MyCookieHandler.cs), and I change the `HandleSignInAsync` method like below.
It also could use middleware to implement it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override async Task HandleSignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties? properties)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity!;
        //if (Options.CheckIpAddress && !user.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "IpAddress"))
        //{
        //    var ipAddress = Context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress!.ToString();
        //    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("IpAddress", ipAddress));
        //}

        //if (Options.CheckUserAgent && !user.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "UserAgent"))
        //{
        //    var userAgent = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        //    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserAgent", userAgent));
        //}
        var tenantId = Context.Request.Headers["TenantId"].ToString();

        user.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(user, MyCookieDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        string cookieValue = Options.TicketDataFormat.Protect(ticket);
        CookieOptions options;
        if (tenantId == "A-Tenant")
        {
            options = new()
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan),
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
            };
        }
        else {
            options = new()
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan),
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
            };
        }
        Response.Cookies.Append(Options.CookieName, cookieValue, options);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - need 24 hours to check it out. Appreciate the heads up.